# Node.js : res.redirect("back") got Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, express, callback, mongoose

I have a little problem on an express.js app.
Can't redirect back after several actions with callbacks.

My applications works with objects called "markers" and they are rated by "sub categories"
The goal of these actions is to merge 2 or more subcategories, move all markers from old to the new subcategoy, and finally, delete the old sub category.

Here is the code :

The action called after checked 2 or more subcategories :

```
exports.postMergeSubCategories = function(req, res) {
    "use strict";

    var data = {};
    data.subCategories  = req.body.subCategoriesChecked;
    data.enName         = req.body.subCategory.enName;
    data.frName         = req.body.subCategory.frName;
    data.deName         = req.body.subCategory.deName;

    if (data.subCategories.length > 1) {
        sscategoryMapper.merge(data, function(err, sscategory) {
            if (err) return console.log(err);
            console.log ('Sub categories merged !');
            req.flash('mergeMessage', 'Merge completed!');
            res.redirect("back");
        });
    } else { // error
        console.log('Error while merge sub categories. It seems the number of sub categories checked less 2');
        req.flash('mergeMessage', 'An error occured whil merge');
        res.redirect("back");
    }    
};
```

The function sscategoryMapper.merge :

```
module.exports.merge = function(data, callback) {
async.waterfall([
    function(callback){ // create new sub category
        save(data, function(err, sscategory) {
            if (err) return callback(err);
            callback(null, sscategory._id);
        });
    },
    function(sscategoryId, callback){ // update marker2sscategory
        async.each(data.subCategories.split('|'), function(oldSscategoryId, err) { // for each subcategories, update markers2sscategory and remove the old subcategory
            async.waterfall([
                function(callback) { // update maker2sscategory to set the new sscategoryId to all target markers
                    marker2sscategoryMapper.update(sscategoryId, oldSscategoryId, function(err) {
                        if (err) return callback(err);
                        callback(null, oldSscategoryId);
                    });
                },
                function(oldSscategoryId, callback) { // delete the old sscategory
                    remove(oldSscategoryId, function(err) {
                        if (err) return callback(err);
                        callback();
                    });
                }
            ], function(err) {
                if (err) return callback(err);
                callback();
            });
        }, function(err) {
            callback(); 
        });
        callback(null, sscategoryId);
    }
], function (err, result) {
    if (err) return callback(err);
    callback(null, result);
});
};
```

**UPDATE**
First problem here : I called 2 times the callback ... This piece of code moved to that :

```
        }, function(err) {
            callback(null, sscategoryId);
        });
    }
], function (err, result) {
    if (err) return callback(err);
    callback(null, result);
});
};
```

**UPDATE END**

The function marker2sscategoryMapper.update :

```
module.exports.update = function(to, from, callback) {
// update marker2sscategory with the new subcategory
dbMarker2sscategory.update({'_sscategory' : from}, {
    '_sscategory' : to
}, {multi: true}, function(err) {
    if (err) return callback(new Error(err));
    callback(null, to);
});
}
```

And the function remove :

```
var remove = module.exports.remove = function(id, callback) {
dbSscategory.remove({'_id' : id}, function(err) {
    if (err) return callback(new Error(err));
    callback(null, id);
});
};
```

If I comment "res.redirect("back")", it will works.
Else, the error is : "Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');" 2 times.

I read that one of the causes can be duplicate callbacks ... But I don't see that in my code.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.'); issue mainly comes when a response is sent and after that some request is still there.Can you check with the call backs

Comment: `postMergeSubCategories` is probably being called multiple times. Where are you using it?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Nope, `postMergeSubCategories` is called only one time. That's a form post called by a route (`router.post('/admin/post_merge_sub_categories', functions.loggedInSu, adminRoutes.postMergeSubCategories);`)

Comment: I found an error in my code with async.each callback, please, see the update. But the problem still the same ...